# Why have typescript property decorators stopped working after an upgrade?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio, tsconfig, typescript-decorator

I have a simple TypeScript `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    ...
```

And a class that uses a decorator:

```
class MyClass {
    @myDecorator()
    myField: any;
}
```

The decorator causes `myField` to be emitted as a property that uses a `__decorate` function, the `myDecorator` function is passed to it.

After upgrading to the latest version (4.2.4) this stopped working in Visual Studio 2019, but it continues to work in VS Code (using 4.3.5) and continuous integration tools (in both 4.3.5 and older 3.* TypeScript releases).

After some investigation it appears that the emitted JavaScript has changed to include the fields explicitly, but *only* in the TypeScript 4.2.4 embedded in Visual Studio 2019. These explicit fields cause the `__decorate` to fail to create the new property with the same name.

Why has the emitted JS changed?

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR**: The fix for TypeScript property decorators breaking when you upgrade TypeScript is to add `"useDefineForClassFields": false` to your `tsconfig.json`.

This is due to a breaking change in TypeScript that was optional in 3.7, but appears to be the default in 4.2 (but not 4.3), and the way the embedded version of TypeScript in Visual Studio 2019 ignores settings.

Firstly we have a new flag: `useDefineForClassFields` - turning this on causes `tsc` to emit fields directly. This is *expected* to break decorators, but is [apparently by design](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35081) (even though it means `useDefineForClassFields` and `experimentalDecorators` now break each other).

As `useDefineForClassFields` is a breaking change it's supposed to default to `false`. However, to align with the ECMAScript standard it [*should* default to `true` when `target` is `ESNext` or `ES2020`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45584#issuecomment-906341134).

It doesn't. It defaults to `false` *except* in Visual Studio, where it defaults to `true`, regardless of your `tsconfig`.

Comment: _Is_ that undocumented? [The `tsconfig.json` docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields) link to [the 3.7 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) which do note _"This can cause quite a bit of fallout for existing code..."_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ah, I meant the decision to default it to true sometime after 3.7 and before 4.2 was undocumented. It was pretty clearly an experiment in 3.7, one I thought had failed given it breaks decorators (one of the main reasons to use TS rather than JS with `ts-check` for us). I'll clarify.